# mongoose retrieves empty array from MongoDB (NodeJS/AWS Lambda)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, aws-lambda

I'm creating a connection for my MongoDB Atlas using NodeJS in a AWS Lambda function. I was able to make a successful connection, but when I do the `.find({})` to get all data I get an empty array.

**Lambda**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let conn = null;

const uri = 'mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@todo-fnddg.mongodb.net/test';
let M = null;
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
  nodejs-aws-lambda-mongodb-atlas
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  if (conn == null) {
    conn = await mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
      bufferCommands: false,
      bufferMaxEntries: 0,
      useNewUrlParser: true
    });
    M = conn.model('Todo', new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        date: Date,
        status: String
      }
    ));
  }


  const doc =  M.find({});
  console.log('items in the DB')
  console.log(doc);

  return null;
};
```

Documentation Mongoose AWS Lambda:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/lambda.html

**UPDATE:**

```
 M.find({}).exec().then(function(allDocs){
    console.log('getting al docs')
    console.log(allDocs)//[]
  });
```

**MongoDB Atlas**

[image]

Comment: Should have been `mongoose.model` instead of `conn.model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) is async so I think you need to do:

```
M.find({}).exec().then(function(allDocs){
   //do your thing
});
```

or await it

```
let alldocs = await M.find({});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I didn't work tho. I have updated my question

Comment: What happens when you use await M.find({})?